# How do I format date using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data 'df' shows data  'Date' as 1970-01-01 00:00:00.019990103 when this is formatted to date_to using pandas. How do I show the date as 01/03/1999?

Answer (score 1):

consider LoneWanderer's comment for next time and show some of the code that you have tried.

I would try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print(now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

You can print now to see that is in the same format that you have and after that is formatted to the format required.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the actual date is in last 10 chars of your source string.

To convert such strings to a *Timestamp* (ignoring the starting part), run:

```
df.Date = df.Date.apply(lambda src: pd.to_datetime(src[-8:]))
```

It is worth to consider to keep this date just as *Timestamp*, as it
simplifies operations on date / time and apply your formatting only in printouts.

But if you want to have this date as a string in "your" format, in the
"original" column, perform the second conversion (*Timestamp* to *string*):

```
df.Date = df.Date.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```